# Why Only usercontrol can't use binding while others can use it?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a question about WPF. There are two component.
1. MainWindow
2. ClothesController: UserControl

MainWindow makes a instance of class 'Shoes' as 'shoes1' with property value 'Size' = 170. This instance is attached to the MainWindow as 'DataContext' and can be easily referenced by Label control 'label_1'. So, label_1 displays 170. Good as expected.

And I made one user control; ClothesController
It has a DependencyProperty 'Value' and bound to UserControl. And a label control refers to this value using same method as 'MainWindow'. The default value is zero.

With this control, I made two instances of 'ClothesController'.
Using exposed DP 'Value', I assigned a value to one instance as binding and for another one, I just assigned an integer directly inside XAML.

The results are
controller_1 is 0; default of DP
controller_2 is 180; As expected
label_1 is 170; As expected

And I can't understand this. Am I missing something?
I'm new to WPF so what I thought is that whatever the type of control is, if it has a modifiable property, then whatever the input is, if the type is matched with that of property, it should be referenced.

Here're the full code. From MainWindow to Usercontrol

++MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="FieldUserControl_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FieldUserControl_test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:ClothesController Name = "controller_1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Value="{Binding Path=Size}" Label="Size"/>
        <local:ClothesController Name = "controller_2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" Label="Height"/>
        <Label Name = "label_1" Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding Path=Size}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

++cs for MainWindow

```
namespace FieldUserControl_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shoes shoes1 = new Shoes() { Size = 170, Height = 200 };
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = shoes1;
        }

    }

    public class Clothes
    {
        public int Size { set; get; }
        public int Height { set; get; }
    }

    public class Shoes : Clothes
    {
    }
}
```

++UserControl; ClothesController

```
<UserControl x:Class="FieldUserControl_test.ClothesController"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FieldUserControl_test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Grid Name="GridRoot" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Label}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Name="Tb_shoes_size" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

++cs for UserControl

```
namespace FieldUserControl_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ClothesController.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ClothesController : UserControl
    {
        public ClothesController()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GridRoot.DataContext = this;
            //or
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public string Label
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }

        }

        public int Value
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(ClothesController), new PropertyMetadata(""));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(ClothesController), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your description does not seem to match your source code. You using names/identifiers (shoes!) in your explanation that are completely different from your source code example (clothes?) makes me doubt about whether you actually copied the correct source in your question...

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment. Shoes is inherited from Clothes with all its properties.

Comment: You seem to refuse acknowledging or fail in understanding that your description does not match your source code. Where/what is SizeDisplayer? Where/what are "displayer_1"/"displayer_2" in the source code of your question? Etc, etc... Good luck...

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I made a mess with displayer & controller. Figure was also making it complicated. I deleted it. For the Shoes, it is inherited from Clothes. For this one, I couldn't understand you. May I ask you about this too?